# Does reads of nonexistent entity billed in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

[Pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing#entity_reads) of Google Cloud datastore gives information about entity reads and says

> You are billed for the number of entities you read. Aggregation queries contribute to the number of entities read as described below.

But gives no clarification about reads that doesn't return any entities.

Let's assume that I'm trying to create cache based on Datastore and I estimate to have 100000 cache misses monthly.

Will I pay for them as usual reads, or those reads will be free of charge?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/billing-questions#usage_dashboard_discrepancies) , get operations that do not return any data also count as a read operation; this applies to Firestore in both Datastore and Native mode.If you are using Google Cloud Datastore for your caching needs, then any cache misses will be billed at the same rate as regular reads.

You can also explore the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=02c15426-102d-44e9-be1d-bf0b5c4f3d2f) to get an estimate and see what is actually charged.